# CoreText rendering text glitch

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

I am working on a new app.  I render different documents from an NSAttributedString using Core Text.  I am having trouble with strange glitches in the rendering of the text.  It doesn't happen with every document.  There doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason to when it appears or not.

Here is a cropped screen shot here to demonstrate the problem.

[image: Glitch in rendering]

Here is a line from the same screenshot that is rendered correctly.

[image: Correct rendering]

**The screenshots are from the same screenshot and the same document.**

When the problem occurs, there are usually only 2-3 consecutive lines of text that are rendered incorrectly.  The rest of the document is fine.

Here is the code that I use to render the text in drawRect:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

float viewHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, viewHeight);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0));

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(PADDING_LEFT, -PADDING_TOP, self.bounds.size.width-20.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, bounds);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)attrString);
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
CFRelease(framesetter);
CFRelease(path);
CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

**EDIT:** This problem does not appear to exist on the iPhone 4, only on the 3GS that I have for testing.

The glitch is always in the middle of a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the various settings to affect the subpixel rendering of text. You can see various options on line 259 in https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML/blob/master/Classes/DTCoreTextLayoutFrame.m

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'll give that a try later today, hopefully!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I tried each of those options and all of those options together.  While they did make a difference in how the text was rendered, none of them solved the glitch.

Comment: Is this a regular drawRect or are you using this in a drawLayer of a CATiledLayer? Could it be that the break occurs at the corner of a tile?

Comment: It is in drawRect.  The glitch always occurs somewhere in the middle of the text.  It is only a line or two and the rest of the text looks fine.  It also does not occur on the iPhone 4.  I'm assuming that the Retina Display may make a difference with how the text is rendered.  Honestly, I think this might be a bug in iOS.

Comment: Can you try out my open source project https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML if this occurs in the same situations?

Comment: I have been looking at your code a lot.  Very interesting stuff, but right now above my head.  It does NOT have the same text glitches that my code has, but I can't figure out why.  Your code is a lot more complex than I need so I don't really want to drop it into my project.  I notice that you use drawInContext instead of putting the code in drawRect.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: drawInContext is what's actually called by the UIView's layer for drawing. By putting this code in there it works regardless of the layer class used by the UIView, i.e. also CATiledLayer which is useful for larger documents.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The only thing I can think of at this point is that there is some sort of bug in CTFrameSetter/CTFrame.  In your code, you lay out each line individually, whereas in mine I use the auto-layout.  I'm going to make a bug report and see where that takes me.

Comment: not true. I'm layouting the entire CTFrame in one go. But I DRAW individual glyph runs by themselves because I need to do additional drawing for certain things like underline, strikeout etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I stand corrected.  However, I do not draw anything individually.  I let CT set the entire frame itself.

Comment: It has been renamed to DTCoreText.